# How to Include image in a C# Model and insert the Document in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, image, models

I want to create a model for a student in asp.net mvc and i want to know how i can include an image with the mode.

Is there any other way than just using the image DataURI?

My Goal is that I want to provide security so that images cannot be seen by others.
I am doing a project on ASP.Net MVC using MongoDB

Comment: i think my question is a little different

Comment: "Images cannot be seen by others" by whom? Protect from whom?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking for. It is unclear to whom and where the image should be unavailable. But I'll try to give some hints. This will not be copy/"pastable" and needs to be adjusted to match your data/models.

I would separate the image from the model in mongo. I.e. The "Student model" should hold an Id to it's image which is stored in a collection of student images.

In your web page fetch the image via a controller action like this. If you want to hide it for all other users than the student itself then you need to just show it when the user match a certain criteria. I assume since you are talking about security that you have login (Identity) up and running.

```
@if (User.Identity.Name == @studentModel.UniqueName)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetStudentImage", "StudentController", new {id = studentModel.ImageId})"
}
```

In your controller you fetch the image from the mongo database. (This is just from the top of my head and will not match your models, so you would have to adjust)

```
public Task<ActionResult> GetStudentImage(string id)
{
     var image = mongo.GetCollection<Image>("Image").AsQueryable().First(x => x.Id == id);
   return File(image.ImageBytes.ToArray(), "image/png"); // the image in bytes
}
```